# Как сделать трекинг модели (чтобы элементы UI (модельки three.js) "смотрели" в камеру)

Tags: javascript, three.js

с помощью `three.js` подгружается некоторая 3D модель. Около этой модели расположены элементы UI (белые кружочки)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При клике на каждый из элементов UI (белые кружочки) выполняется какой то обработчик.

**Проблема:** Если вращать модельку, то вместе с моделькой вращаются и элементы UI. И происходит такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** Как сделать так, чтобы "лицевая сторона" элементов UI, независимо от того как перемещает пользователь камеру, "смотрела" прямо в камеру?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let ui_elems = [ // содержит имена объектов которым нужно смотреть в камеру
    "UI_element1",
    "UI_element2",
    "UI_element3",
    "UI_element4",
    "UI_element5",
    "UI_element6",
    "UI_element7"
];

function rotate_ui(scene, ui_elems, camera_rotation) {
    
    scene.traverse((child) => {


        for (let i = 0; i < ui_elems.length; i++)
            if (child.name == ui_elems[i]) {
                child.rotation.z = camera_rotation.z;
                child.rotation.y = camera_rotation.y;
                child.rotation.x = camera_rotation.x;
            }

    });
}

function animate() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    rotate_ui(scene, ui_elems, camera.rotation);

}
```

Comment: Возможно, что имеет смысл при загрузке модели через `.traverse()` найти нужные элементы и поместить их в массив (допустим `ui_elements`), и потом в цикле анимации выполнять 

`ui_elements.forEach(ui_el => {ui_el.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion);})`

 Получается не так много кода, плюс снимается необходимость на каждую итерацию цикла анимации пробегать по всей модели в поисках нужных элементов.